# Copy text - doubled letters (Mathjax)

Tags: mathjax

I want to ask You about problem with "doubled letters" meanwhile copy on pages with Mathjax.

1. On first page I try to copy Mathjax formula like this:
   [Look at picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ick.png)

Then I receive on Notepad: ∫x2dx=2x+C∫x2dx=2x+C

So it copy two times the same formula.

2. On second page I try to copy Mathjax formula like this:
   [Look at picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9GN9.png)

And here when I copy Mathjax formula then I receive in Notepad: (x+1)2=?

So here it copy formula correct, it didn't copy doubled.

And here is my question - what is the reason, that first page gives doubled formulas meanwhile copy? This is big problem for me, because Google read formula on first page also "twice". How can I repair this problem?

(I can't put links to these pages, because I have too low reputation)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to MathJax's [AssistiveMML extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/accessibility-features.html#legacy-support-via-assistivemml-js) which injects visually-hidden but accessible MathML into the DOM alongside MathJax's output.

While the MathML fragment gets `user-select:none` (to prevent copy&paste), this CSS feature is not supported on all browsers.

As a reader, you can disable the extension via the MathJax Menu (righ/cmd-click on an expression) under Accessibility > Assisitve MathML.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this script to copy MathJax elements as LaTeX , or MML directly! It use jQuery, but you can manualy remove it:

```
var MathJaxRevertRendering = function(html){
    var $ = jQuery;
    var stencil = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
    var replaceMathJax = function(){
        if ($(this).parents('.mjx-chtml').length) return;

        var math = $(this).find('math');
        if (math.length){
            var latex = math.find('annotation[encoding="LaTeX"]');
            if (latex.length){
                $(this).replaceWith( '$$' + $.trim(latex.html()) + '$$');
            }else{
                $(this).replaceWith( math[0].outerHTML );
            }
        }
    };
    if (stencil.find('.mjx-chtml').length){
        stencil.find('.MathJax_Preview,script').remove();
        stencil.find('.mjx-chtml').each(replaceMathJax);
        html = stencil.html();
    }
    return html;
};

document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    var getSelectionHtml = function() {
        var html = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var container = document.createElement("div");
                for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                html = container.innerHTML;
            }
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
                html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
            }
        }
        return html;
    };
    var html = getSelectionHtml();
    var htmlLatexed = MathJaxRevertRendering(html);
    if (html != htmlLatexed){
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', htmlLatexed);
        var removeHTML = true;
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', htmlLatexed.split(/(<math)|(<\/math>)/).reduce(function(buffer, val){
            if (!val) return buffer;
            if (val == '<math' || val == '</math>'){
                removeHTML = !removeHTML;
                buffer += val;
            }else{
                buffer+=removeHTML ? jQuery('<div>'+val+'</div>').text() : val;
            }
            return buffer;
        }, ''));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And then, any who copy something with MathJax element on your site: will see it math well-formatted, when paste it to any editor.